# Outlook 2013 crashes when sending mail

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2013

Outlook 2013 crashes when sending mail:

I have just installed Outlook 2013 US version on my Win7 pc. Everytime I send a mail, Outloook chrashes, with the same error:

```
    Problem signature:
      Problem Event Name:   BEX
      Application Name: outlook.exe
      Application Version:  15.0.4454.1000
      Application Timestamp:    509a3a5d
      Fault Module Name:    unknown
      Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
      Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
      Exception Offset: 53ee0122
      Exception Code:   c0000005
      Exception Data:   00000008
      OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
      Locale ID:    1030

    Additional information about the problem:
      LCID: 1033
      skulcid:  1033
```

Comment: It seems to be related to DEP. Here is similar problem: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/problem-event-name-bex-error-message/cf5baf73-0877-4070-abfb-a2c3a17a9e10

Comment: I have a similar problem, Outlook 2013 crashing every second time when I click to send email. Not very happy. DEP cannot be removed for OUTLOOK.EXE.

Answer (score 0):

you should try go to

option/add-inns
manage ==> GO (klik)
and try to uncheck software no coloration with outlook ex avast antivirus